# How do I convert list to table in Excel 2003

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2003

I have a list:

```
    date  item name    quantity
1.7.2014    A              5
1.7.2014    B              2
1.7.2014    C              10
2.7.2014    B              5
3.7.2014    A              1
4.7.2014    A              7
```

I want this list as below table in excel

```
ITEM NAME    1.7.2014     2.7.2014     3.7.2014       4.7.2014
A               5                        1               7
B               2            5     
C               10
```

How do I do this?

Comment: use Pivot tables

Comment: no because pivot tables aggregate data and this is not what is being asked for

Answer (score 0):

As suggestes by @Sathya, use pivot tables as explained by Microsoft in [this article](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/quick-start-create-a-pivottable-report-HA010359471.aspx).

Long story short:

1. Select your list
2. Insert a pivot table (Insert --> Pivot table or Data --> Pivot table, depending on your Excel version).
3. With your cursor inside the pivot table, put the `Item name` in the `Column labels`, `Date` in `Row labels` and `Quantity` in `Values` (select Sum to sum all quantities for the same date/item name combination).

Comment: Pivot tables aggregate data, this is not what is being asked for. The question actually wants a crosstab from the list and not a pivot table

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Power Query Add-In for this. It has a Pivot command that should achieve what you want:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/powerBI/bi-blog.aspx?blog=91d46819-8472-40ad-a661-2c78acb4018c%3A10553536&WT.mc_id=OO_PowerQuery_Update#pivot

I've built a solution to a similar problem which you can view or download - its "Power Query demo - Pivot rows into columns.xlsx" in my One Drive:

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=4FA287BBC10EC562%21398